# How to manage resources that cannot be deep-copied in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17

I am creating a class that manages a resource that should not be "deep copied", that is, there can only ever be one instance of the underlying resource, even if multiple objects have access this same resource.

However, allowing multiple objects to access this resource is also dangerous, as one object could go out of scope, and self-destruct, which will also destroy the resource. In this case, is it reasonable to only define a move constructor (without allowing for shallow copies)? Or is there some way to support shallow copies, so that multiple objects can reference the same resource, but the resource will not be destroyed if at least one object still has access to the resource?

For context, the resource being managed is an OpenGL shader, and each object has the ID of this shader as one of it's members, which it uses to tell OpenGL to delete the shader when necessary.

Comment: The usualyy way is to create a non-copyable object to manage the resource, then use a std::shared_ptr to refcount if you want mulitple references.  std::make_shared can be used to construct the basic non-copyable object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you are looking for `std::shared_ptr` or parallel solution; `std::shared_ptr` is used to share pointers to a single object, which is destroyed only after **all** of the shared pointers are cleared. Thus, while we still have a reference to the object, it remains valid.

Even if you are not looking to use `shared_ptr`, the idea behind it is to use a ***reference counter***, which is shared by all objects that refer to the same resource - each time you call a constructor/copy constructor/copy-assignment, you increase the shared counter by 1, and in the destructor, you decrease it by 1, and if (**and only if**) it reaches 0 then you release the underlying resource.

Also, for completeness of the answer, I should add that for `std::shared_ptr`, there is in addition `std::weak_ptr`, which denotes access without shared ownership - it allows one to access a resource held by a `std::shared_ptr` ***while it is alive***, but can be reset automatically if all of the `std::shared_ptr` that refer to the resource are destroyed. It is rare to see usage of it, but it is possible to use it, nevertheless.

Comment: +1 so if I understand correctly, each instance of my object, instead of containing the ID itself, would contain a shared pointer to a special "ID class", and then when of the objects that contain that shared pointer go out of scope, the destructor of the ID class would be called automatically? (Which could destroy the underlying resource)

Comment: @TrevorGalivan yes, the `std::shared_ptr` is deleting the underlining pointer only when all of the references are gone. However, notice that it is an error to create two ***different*** `std::shared_ptr` on the same pointer - after you have created the first one, you must ***copy*** into other `shared_ptr`!

Comment: @TrevorGalivan You should consult the cpp reference for shared_ptr for more information, but it is a super useful tool, along-side the `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @TrevorGalivan it's also important to note that std::shared_ptr can be given custom destructors if you need to close a file or release a resource. shared_ptr is also thread-safe, so it works across multiple threads.

Comment: I implemented this and it worked great! The resultant code is much neater now, and the shader object can now be safely passed wherever it is needed without destroying the underlying resource.